# Has something changed in caching data in ASP.NET-MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I need an application level cache in my MVC3 project.

I want to use something like this in a controller:

```
using System.Web.Caching;    

protected IMyStuff GetStuff(string stuffkey)
{
    var ret = Cache[stuffkey];
    if (ret == null)
    {
        ret = LoadStuffFromDB(stuffkey);
        Cache[stuffkey] = ret;
    }
    return (IMyStuff)ret;
}
```

This fails because Cache["foo"] don't compile as "System.Web.Caching.Cache is a 'type' but used like a 'variable'".

I see that Cache is a class, but there are quite a few examples on the net when it is used like Session["asdf"] in the controller like it is a property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a property named `Session` in controller but there is no property named `Cache`.
You should use `HttpRuntime.Cache` static property in order to get `Cache` object.
For example:

```
using System.Web.Caching;    

protected IMyStuff GetStuff(string stuffkey)
{
    var ret = HttpRuntime.Cache[stuffkey];
    if (ret == null)
    {
        ret = LoadStuffFromDB(stuffkey);
        HttpRuntime.Cache[stuffkey] = ret;
    }
    return (IMyStuff)ret;
}
```

Comment: Actually your example is the same as mine character by character but the answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

There are newer methods in MVC for caching data
like - 
[OutputCache(Duration=3)]
You can also specify this in your web.config file
as seen here:
http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/07/caching-infrastructure-in-mvc4-with-c-caching-controller-actions/
This is much more efficient and readily available if you are developing in MVC

- however, if you wish to use the previous method for caching you might consider 
  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["variable"] = datasetresult` or `listObjectResult`
  i.e.,
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["POSSEData"] = MyDevObjBO.GetListOfObjects();

then reassign as needed :
i.e.,
        grdViewStuff.DataSource = (List)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["POSSEData"];

Comment: What are you refferring by "newer methods"?